# Trying to create a static page for my module using page callback in hook_menu

Tags: 7

I’m taking first steps in building a module for Drupal 7 and am trying to create a static page within hook_menu function. In the $items array, for ‘page callback' I create an very simple function named ‘semi_static_page’. This simple function returns some html. the code is below.

```
$items['admin/config/media/tsoundcloud/config/soundcloud_static'] =             array(
    'title' => t('Semi Static Page'),
    'description' => 'Temp page to show data',
    'page callback' => 'semi_static_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

function semi_static_page(){
  $output = 'this is some output, etc…….’;
  return $output;
}
```

But this page generate the following error.

**Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /Users/tomcarden/Sites/sweetteas/includes/form.inc on line 1079**

How can this be resolved? Ultimately I want to load an .inc in the semi_static_page function.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$output = 'this is some output, etc…….`’`;

If you see in the above line, you are using wrong sign, which I have  highlighted after ...... That is wrong. It should be `'`

Above isuue is for sure!!!!

---

Other just my suggestion, As I am also learning Hooks, may be TOTALLY WRONG but for your attention.

I have changed code as below and after that, I have written my point..

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/media/tsoundcloud/config/soundcloud_static'] = array(
    'title' => 'Semi Static Page',
    'description' => 'Temp page to show data',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_semistaticpage', 
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
 }

/**
 * Page callback
 */
function mymodule_semistaticpage(){
  $output = 'this is some output, etc…….';
  return $output;
}
```

The following points are for code which you have posted in main-question, and I have corrected those in above code,

- See function name, it should start with module name.
- The _page(), may creating confusion as some hook has `_page()` part..so I did change function name to mymodule_semistaticpage()
- where is return $items;?
- I think `title` do not need, t()?

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is very clearly mentioned in error statement , you need to replace (’) with (') without parentheses of-course.

other suggestions:
1: Title field do not require t() function 
2: Description field should be written in t() function
3: Never ever forget to return $items array.
4: It is customary to start call back function names with your module name.
5: Always document your code for future purposes.
6: Your call back function should return content in a theme-able formate for example ('#type' => 'markup') etc